# Install Debian dependencies on Cloud Foundry for use with puppeteer

Tags: ubuntu, debian, cloud-foundry

Let me just be clear. I'm a newbie to PCF, so it might look a little foolish how I sound.
So I have this application where i'm using cloud foundry for deployment. I use the cflinux3 stack and the node and apt buildpacks.
The application uses puppeteer with nodejs to generate a pdf from an HTML file.
The issue I'm facing is that, on a Linux OS, inorder for wither chrome or chromium to run you'd require a set of shared dependencies with the OS.
I tried installing these with the aptbuildpack by specifying the package names on the apt.yml file. I have specified all the required debian repositories as well.
The issue is that even though some of the dependencies get downloaded, some others error out.
Looks something like this:
E: Unable to locate package libnss3
E: Unable to locate package libgbm-dev

my apt yml file looks something around that

```
---

truncatesources: true

cleancache: true
repos:
- deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
- deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
- deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
- deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
- deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

packages:
- gconf-service
- libasound2 
- libatk1.0-0
- libc6 
- libcairo2 
- libcups2 
- libdbus-1-3
- libexpat1 
- libfontconfig1
- libgcc1 
- libgconf-2-4
- libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
- libglib2.0-0
- libgtk-3-0
- libnspr4 
- libpango-1.0-0
- libpangocairo-1.0-0
- libstdc++6
- libx11-6
- libx11-xcb1
- libxcb1 
- libxcomposite1 
- libxcursor1
- libxdamage1 
- libxext6 
- libxfixes3 
- libxi6 
- libxrandr2 
- libxrender1 
- libxss1 
- libxtst6 
- ca-certificates
- fonts-liberation
- libappindicator1
- libnss3 
- lsb-release
- xdg-utils
- wget
- libgbm-dev
```

Just wanted to know if there'd be any other way to install these dependencies like downloading the debian packages manually and then specifying the local file on the apt.yml

I hope someone could help me out with this. I'm stuck on this for quite a while and so the release is getting delayed.

Comment: If it's failing to find something, either you have the wrong package name (make sure the package name is correct for Ubuntu Bionic) or you're having Internet issues and it cannot connect to the repo. It sounds like the name might be wrong, but the full error message isn't posted so it's hard to say.

Comment: A couple of other notes: 1.) you don't need to list the default Ubuntu repos. I would remove all the ones listed under ubuntu.com. Just so there's no conflict. 2.) You can point to deb files directly, just list a URL to the DEB file instead of the package name. See the first example: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack#buildpack-user-documentation (the last package is just a URL to a DEB file).